# Jquery animate issue

Tags: jquery

I have a small issue whereby I am trying to scroll up to the 1st span when the block is shown when validation takes place.

I have tried the following code so that once the user attempts to submit if the span is displayed with the class 'required' the page should scroll up.

HTML:

```
<span id="_userExists" runat="server" visible="false" class="invalid">
```

This is in the markup and the required class is applied after validation takes place. I am not really sure how this affects the jquery animation due to it running server side and the made visible upon a validation error.

Jquery:

```
$("input[type=submit]").live('click', function(){
 console.log('clicked');
 $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('.required').first().offset().top
 }, 600);
});
```

I have tried the same script after the error messages are displayed inline but the scroll simply wont happen. If I select another element, h2 for example, then the page scrolls. This scrolling to the 1st error needs to happen on page load as well as the submit button for client side validation.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you supply some html markup or put this issue in jsfiddle.net so we can all test it?

Answer (score 0):

if ur all spans got required class, use this to reach first one

```
$("input[type=submit]").live('click', function(){
 console.log('clicked');
 $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('.required:first').offset().top//<--here
 }, 600);
});
```